# Verification of proof of the Sequence of Arithmetic Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose $\left\{b_{n}\right\}$ is a sequence of real numbers which converges to $M$, so that $b_{n} \neq 0$ for each $n$, and $M \neq 0$. Prove that the sequence $\{ \frac{1}{b_n} \}$ converges to $\frac 1M$ by using the following steps:

(a) Prove that there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $| b_{n} | \geq \delta$ for all $n$.  (Hint: consider $\epsilon = \frac{|M|}{2}$.)

(b). Prove that $\frac{1}{| b_n M |}  < \frac{2}{\delta | M |}$.

(c). Prove that $\{ \frac{1}{b_n} \}$ converges to $\frac{1}{M}$. (Hint: use the fact that $| \frac{1}{b_n} - \frac{1}{M} | = 1/\left\vert b_{n}M\right\vert\left\vert b_{n} - M\right\vert$.

For part (a): First we prove that ${|b_n|}$ converges to $|M|$. Second we explicitly show that a $\delta$ > 0 with $| b_{n} | \geq \delta$ for all $n$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since the sequence $\left\{b_{n}\right\}$ converges to $M$, there is an $N$ is an element of the set of real numbers, so that if $n$ belongs to the set of natural numbers $n$> $N$ then $|b_n - M|$ < $\epsilon$. Suppose that $n$ is in the set of natural numbers and $n$ > $N$. Then by the triangle inequality, we have $||b_n| - |M||\leq \ |b_n - M|$ < $\epsilon$. Thus, the sequence ${|b_n|}$ converges to $|M|$.

For the second part, we let $\delta = \frac{|M|}{2}$. Applying the definition of convergence with $\epsilon = \frac{|M|}{2}$ gives us an $N$ which belongs to a set of reals, so that if $n$ belongs to the set of natural numbers and $n$ > $N$ then $||bn| - |M||< |M|/2$. Then, if $n \gt N$ we have $-|M|/2 \lt bn \lt |M|/2$. Adding $|M|$ gives $|M|/2 \lt b_n \lt M + |M|/2$. In particular, if $n \gt N$, then $|b_n| \gt |M|/2 = \delta$ .

For part (b): $\frac{1}{| b_n M |}$ = $\frac{1}{| b_n| |M| }$ > $\frac{1}{\delta |M| }$ < $\frac{2}{\delta |M|}$ (since $\frac{1}{|M|}$ < $\frac{2}{|M|}$).

For part (c): Since the sequence $\left\{b_{n}\right\}$ converges to $M$  ≠ 0, by part a) there is an $N_0$ in $R$ (the set of real numbers) and $\delta$ > 0 so that if $n$ belongs to the set of natural numbers and $n$ > $N$ then $| b_{n} | \geq \delta$. Then if $n$ > $N_0$, $\frac{1}{|b_{n}|}$ < $\frac{1}{\delta}$. Let $\epsilon$ > 0. Since sequence $\left\{b_{n}\right\}$ converges to $M$, there is an $|N_b|$ in $R$ so that if n belongs to the set of natural numbers and $n$ > $N_b$ then $|b_n - M|$ < $\epsilon$ $\delta$ $|M|$. let $N$ = max($N_0$, $N_b$). Suppose that $n$ belongs to the set of naturals and $n$ > $N$. Then $| \frac{1}{b_n} - \frac{1}{M} | = 1/\left\vert b_{n}M\right\vert\left\vert b_{n} - M\right\vert$ = $\frac{|b_n - M|}{|b_n| |M|}$ < $\frac{\epsilon\delta |M|}{|b_n| |M|}$ = $\epsilon$. Hence, $\{ \frac{1}{b_n} \}$ converges to $\frac{1}{M}$.

So what you guys think about my proof?

Comment: My favorite LaTeX tools: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php , and http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html  I changed '<' to '\lt' ("less than") in your post.

Comment: Not sure that this conclusion holds: $||b_n|−M| \lt |M|/2$. Then, if $n\gt N$ we have $−|M|/2 \lt b_n \lt |M|/2$.

Comment: "Second we show that $|b_n|\ge\delta$ for all $n$." At the point where you write this, the sentence makes no sense, since you have not said yet what $\delta$ is. Better to write something like: Second, we explicitly show a $\delta>0$ with $|b_n|\ge\delta$ for all $n$. Or even: Second, we show that $|b_n|\ge|M|/2$ for all $n$. On a different note, there is a typo in several places, where you write $bn$ instead of $b_n$.

Comment: A word on style: "there is an $N$ is an element of the set of real numbers" makes no sense. You could fix it by writing "there is an $N$ that belongs to the set ..." or "there is an $N$ in the set ...", but both phrasings are awkward. Better to say: "there is a real $N$". Similarly, it is better to say "if $n$ is a natural number larger than $N$, then".

Comment: Thanks.I don't know to write "belongs to" E in Latex.

Comment: Minor typo in the third line of your argument for the second part: Where you write $||b_n|−M|$, you probably mean $||bn|−|M|$.

Comment: You probably just want to say it in words, but if you feel the symbol is better, type \in: $\in$.

Comment: Thanks. Other than the typos is my proof fine?

Comment: So far, so good, but I just finished reading the argument for b). There are several other typos in there: $−|M|/2<bn<|M|/2$ should be $-|M|/2<|b_n|-|M|<|M|/2$. Then $|M|/2<b_n<M+|M|/2$ should be $|M|/2<|b_n|<3|M|/2$.

Comment: Your proof for b) is fine, except for the $>$ that should be $<$. But note that whoever wrote the hint perhaps had something different in mind: They expected you to have $|b_n|\ge|\delta|$, so $|b_n|>|\delta|/2$, so $\frac1{|b_n||M|}<\frac2{|\delta||M|}$.

Comment: In your write-up of part c): "converges to $M$ is not equal to 0" makes no sense. Either write "converges to $M$, and recall that by assumption $M$ is not equal to $0$", or use $\ne$ (LaTeX \ne or \neq): "converges to $M\ne0$".

Comment: So part b) should be: $\frac{1}{| b_n M |}$ = $\frac{1}{| b_n| |M| }$ < $\frac{1}{\delta |M| }$ < $\frac{2}{\delta |M|}$ (since $\frac{1}{|M|}$ < $\frac{2}{|M|}$). The hint thing is not intuitive to me. Could you please explain how you went from the hint to the final step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is by accident or by error, but you seem to have mixed at least $b_n$ and $b_n- M$ a few times. How about this approach for the first part:
$|M|\le |b_n|+|M-b_n|$ by the triangle inequality. As you noted, $|M-b_n|<\frac12|M|$ for almost all $n$, hence $|b_n|\ge |M|-|M-b_n|>(1-\frac12)|M|$ for almost all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for part $(a)$.  First prove that if a sequence $b_n \rightarrow M$, then any subsequence also converges to $M$.  This follows since $\forall n \gt N, |b_n - M| \lt \epsilon$ which includes those $b_n$ in the subsequence.  If you want to formalize it more, a subsequence is a sequence $(b_{k_n})$ such that $k_i \lt k_j$ for $i \lt j$ and you also have that $k_n \geq n$.

Argue by contradiction.  If there exist no such $\delta$ intuitively it seems that $b_n$ or subsequence might converge to zero, but since $M \neq 0$, there's a contradiction if a subsequence does.  So we want to construct such a subsequence.  If no such $\delta$ exists, then for $\delta = 1/m$ there exists infinitely many $b_n$ less than less than $\delta$.  Choose one and call it $b_{k_m}$.  Then $(b_{k_m})_{m\geq 1}$ is a subsequence converging to zero since for all $\epsilon \gt 0$...

Something like that.  Sorry I didn't answer w.r.t. the hint for part $(a)$, and I don't know if the above method is valid.  But you should look into it and let me know how it goes.